# Check if a string is unallocated

Tags: c, string, pointers, allocation

This may be a deeper question than I expect, but can you see if a character pointer is unallocated? For example, a string that is unallocated is not `NULL`, as seen from when I ran this code:

```
char *ptr; /* Unallocated char pointer */
if (ptr == NULL) {
        ptr = malloc(10); /* Not casted cause it doesn't matter */
        printf("ptr is allocated\n");
        return(0);
}
printf("ptr is unallocated\n");
return(0);
```

When I ran the code, I received the message `ptr is unallocated`. That makes sense because the string could not have memory for a null character. So, is there any way to see if a string is unallocated? Or am I asking the wrong question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible. In your case, `ptr` is *uninitialised*, which means it might contain any value at all, until the first time you assign something to it. It might be `NULL`, or it might not.

Comment: So, then, if I were passing strings to functions and I would need to have already initialized them to `NULL` in all cases?

Comment: Yes, you must always initialise local variables. Otherwise, you can't make any assumptions about what they might be.

Comment: @Trifork: yes, if you want your program to behave properly.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: Ah, I see. I wasn't sure if that also applied to strings, and whether or not `NULL` had any effect on uninitialized pointers.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you defined `ptr` but didn't initialize it. Try this:

```
char *ptr = NULL;
```

It's a good coding style to initialize a pointer to a null pointer in general; it is crucial if you want to test whether it is initialized to some valid string.

Comment: Does setting `ptr` to `NULL` give it a null character, or is it just an acceptable form of initialization? Would you use `malloc()` afterwards to allocate it, or `realloc()`?

Comment: No; setting `ptr` to `NULL` means that `ptr` points to no memory address. You would then call `ptr = malloc(1); *ptr = '\0';` to put a null character in the location pointed to by `ptr`

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this without providing an initial value since unintialized automatic variables will have an *indeterminate value*. They must be initialized; there is no way to determine the initial value of an automatic variables otherwise. In fact using an uninitialized variable is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The draft C99 standard says in section `6.7.8` *Initialization* paragraph *10* says:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate. [...]

and Annex `J.2` *Undefined behavior* paragraph *1* says:

> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:

and includes the following bullet:

> The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is
>   indeterminate (6.2.4, 6.7.8, 6.8).

Comment: I see, so I can never use uninitialized variables in any case.

Comment: @Trifork you should never use the value of an unintialized variable, it is undefined behavior which means your program can literally do anything, although usually the results are behavior that appear normal but can break at anytime or a crash of some sort. The link I provided should be helpful.